# Complete k-partite graph covers all K_k of a graph

Tags: extremal-graph-theory

Suppose that we have a complete graph $G$ of $n$ vertices. What is the minimum number of complete $k$-partite graph (subgraph of $G$) that covers all the complete graph of $k$ vertices of $V(G)$? Are there any results related to this problem? Any lower bounds or upper bounds?

To phrase it in another way. Suppose that there are $n$ students entering in an exam of some multiple choice questions, each has $k$ choices. After the exam, you find that among any $k$ students, there is (at least) a question such that these $k$ students answer differently. Then what is the minimum number of questions in this exam?

For example, when $k=2$, it is asking how many bipartite graph is need to cover a complete graph.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this number is $\log_2(n)$ for $k=2$? What am I missing?

Comment: It is obvious. But what about the general $k$, say $k=3$?

Answer (score 4):

For every graph $G$, the smallest number of complete bipartite subgraphs needed to cover the edges of $G$ is called the *biclique covering number*, and is denoted by $bc(G)$.  The corresponding partitioning problem is called the *biclique partitioning number*, and is denoted by $bp(G)$.  Both these problems have been widely studied, not just for complete graphs.

For complete graphs, it is a classical result of [Graham and Pollak](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/71_05_loop_switching.pdf) that $bp(K_n)=n-1$.  On the other hand, it is easy to show (and this addresses your question), that $bc(K_n) \leq \log(n)$.  Thus, $bp(G)$ and $bc(G)$ can be exponentially far apart.

For a slew of results for $bp(G)$ and $bc(G)$ for other classes of graphs, see the introduction of this [paper](http://lovelace.thi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~jukna/ftp/covering.pdf) by Jukna and Kulikov.

Comment: The case of $k=2$ is not very interesting for covering of the complete graph. I want to know about the general case of $k$.

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you encode the vertices as numbers in base $k$, then you can cover with $\log_k(n)$ complete $k$-bipartite subgraphs.  Not sure if you can do better.

Comment: Sorry that I am not making it clear. I want these $k$-partite subgraphs to cover all the complete graphs of $k$ vertices in $G$, but not just cover $G$.

Answer (score 3):

A graph $G$ can be covered by $l$ $k$-partite subgraphs if and only if $\chi(G) \leq k^l$.  This is easy to see by thinking of the colours as the elements of $[k]^l$.

Note that, in contrast to the situation described in Tony Huynh's answer, the $k$-partite subgraphs are not required to be complete (but it makes no difference if $G = K_n$).

Comment: Isn't this lower bound for $l$ also an upper bound, because given a $k^l$-coloring you can find $l$ different maps from the set of vertices to $\{1,\dots,k\}$ such that each edge connects vertices sent to two different numbers by at least one of the maps? This gives you $l$ $k$-partite graphs. So the answer is exactly $\lceil \log_k n \rceil$ graphs.

Comment: Yes, it's an exact characterisation of the graphs that can be covered in this way.

Comment: Sorry for making it unclear. I change the problem description.